# SQL joined tables and MIN clause

Tags: sql

I am trying to run a query that will display the manager ID and the lowest paid employee for that manager. It will also exclude any groups where the minimum salary is $6000 or less, and the manager is not known. My code with display all of this except the employee who is the lowest paid. Here is my code.

```
select departments.manager_id, employees.salary
from hr.employees, hr.departments, hr.jobs
where employees.department_id = departments.department_id
AND jobs.job_id = employees.job_id
AND departments.manager_id IS NOT NULL
AND salary NOT IN
(select salary
from hr.employees
where salary <= 6000)
```

Comment: It isn't clear how employees is joined to managers.

Comment: You'll need to join the employees in the last SELECT statement with the employees in your main query.

Comment: update your question add the related  table schema, proper data sample and the expected  result

Comment: can you add sample data for your tables and expected output

Comment: I have a departments table, employees table, and jobs table. The departments table is joined to the employees table via department_id. The employees table is joined to the departments table by department_id.

Comment: With my code I can display all the employees whose pay is greater than 6000 and the manager value is not null. I now need help trying to display just the lowest paid person for each manager.

Comment: First never use implicit joins, they are a SQL antipattern and make determining what is wrong more difficult. Next post you schema and sample data and sample results. Getting the right answer depends on understanding the meaning of your data and your business rules and we don't know them at this point.

Comment: which dbms are you working on?

Comment: Your given code does not do what you say it does. `AND salary NOT IN (select salary from hr.employees where salary <= 6000)` can be replaced with `AND salary > 6000`, but that still only excludes jobs with low salaries, not departments where the minimum salary is 6k or lower. It's not possible to answer your question without knowing what dbms you are working with, and it would be much easier with sample data and output as others have mentioned.

Comment: Oracle 11g. Sample Data: HR.JOBS table consist of job_id(PK), job_title, max_salary, min_salary. HR.EMPLOYEES consist of employee_id (PK), last_name, job_id(FK),salary, department_id (FK). HR.DEPARTMENTS table consist of department_id(PK), manager_id

Answer (score 0):

Here is something just based on the EMP table that might help...

```
select * from (
  select min(e1.sal) over( partition by m1.ename ) minsal
, e1.mgr
, e1.ename
, m1.ename Manager
, e1.sal sal
from emp e1
join emp m1
  on e1.mgr = m1.empno
)
where minsal > 1500

    MINSAL        MGR ENAME      MANAGER           SAL
---------- ---------- ---------- ---------- ----------
      3000       7566 FORD       JONES            3000
      3000       7566 SCOTT      JONES            3000
      2450       7839 CLARK      KING             2450
      2450       7839 BLAKE      KING             2850
      2450       7839 JONES      KING             2975
```